# Unicode on Python

Tags: python, utf-8, nltk, python-unicode

I have been trying to run the following code:

```
def split_into_lemmas(features):
    features = unicode(features, 'utf-8', errors='replace').lower()
    words = TextBlob(features).words 
    return [word.lemma for word in words]

bow = CountVectorizer(analyzer=split_into_lemmas).fit(features)
print("Length of Vocabulary:"+str(len(bow.vocabulary_)))
```

I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined
```

Therefore, I tried substituting the unicode command with 'str' in the 2nd line, but I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-9b9bcc3b084f> in <module>
      4     return [word.lemma for word in words]
      5 
----> 6 bow = CountVectorizer(analyzer=split_into_lemmas).fit(features)
      7 print("Length of Vocabulary:"+str(len(bow.vocabulary_)))

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in fit(self, raw_documents, y)
    995         self
    996         """
--> 997         self.fit_transform(raw_documents)
    998         return self
    999 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)
   1029 
   1030         vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents,
-> 1031                                           self.fixed_vocabulary_)
   1032 
   1033         if self.binary:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in _count_vocab(self, raw_documents, fixed_vocab)
    941         for doc in raw_documents:
    942             feature_counter = {}
--> 943             for feature in analyze(doc):
    944                 try:
    945                     feature_idx = vocabulary[feature]

<ipython-input-10-9b9bcc3b084f> in split_into_lemmas(features)
      1 def split_into_lemmas(features):
----> 2     features = str(features, 'utf-8', errors='replace').lower()
      3     words = TextBlob(features).words
      4     return [word.lemma for word in words]
      5 

TypeError: decoding str is not supported
```

I am getting the script from: https://github.com/DipakMajhi/Classify-Industry-for-Companies/blob/master/Classify-Industry-for-Companies.ipynb.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You are running a script intended for Python 2 using Python 3. `unicode` was the name of the type that corresponds to `str` in Python 3. Also in Python 3, you cannot decode a `str` value, because it is strictly a sequence of Unicode code points. You *encode* a `str` value, and *decode* a `bytes` value.

Comment: @chepner, so if I have values that are in text, I cannot convert them into numerical feature vectors?

Comment: You can, but probably not in the way the script does it. Python 2 code often used `str` where it should have used `unicode`, and it can take some work to figure out which type of data (Unicode text or a byte stream encoding Unicode text) is present in a given value.

Comment: That said, it *looks* like the code is trying to decode a UTF-8 byte stream. If `features` is a `byte` value, `features = features.decode()` should work. If the bytes are somehow shoehorned into a `str` object, I don't recall how to properly decode it (sorry).

Comment: @chepner, I got the following error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`. Does it mean that the 'features' I am trying to define is a 'str' object?

Comment: Probably. But it's also possible that `features` is *already* the Unicode string you want, depending on what produced it. For example, if a file was opened in text mode, then its `read` method will already yield a decoded `str` value, rather than a `bytes` value that needs to be decoded.

Comment: Looks like they are already decoded! The code is now running smoothly. I had to download two more packages though: punkt and wordnet.

Comment: Instead of `features = unicode(...).lower()` use `features = features.lower()`.